# Nodejs request data-raw como json

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente curl:

> curl 'http://localhost:9008/updated' \   -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
> -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36' \   -H 'Content-Type:
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \   -H 'Accept-Language:
> es-ES,es;q=0.9' \   --data-raw '{"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}'

En nodejs recibo el body como objeto , es decir, { '{"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}' } y deberia ser un json como se envia en el curl {"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}

```
router.post('/updated' ,express.json() , function (req, res) {
 logger.info(req.body) -> aca recibo un objeto en vez del json
});
```

ALguna idea de como quitar el {'  ?

Comment: Qué quieres decir con que "te llega un objeto y debiera ser un json"? por json quieres decir la representación del objeto como string?

Comment: Me refiero a que me llega { '{"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}' }   pero esto no es un json , si le aplico un typeof me dice q es un object. 
El req.body deberia ser {"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}   no entiendo porqué agrega llaves y comillas simples.

Comment: y si usas `console.log` en vez de `logger.info` ? la sintaxis `{ 'string' } ` no es un objeto literal. Apostaría a que el logger lo decora de más, mal que mal necesita stringificar

Comment: Acabo de hacer la prueba y el console.log me arroja lo mismo que el logger.info { '{"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}' } 

Y el JSON.stringify me hace esto
{"{\"data\":[{\"id\":\"12345\"}]}"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta cambiar la opción `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` por
`Content-Type: application/json`

Puedes intentar usar los métodos de `JSON` para intentar transformar el objeto y luego remover las cosas que no quieras para dejarlo como quieras, los métodos son `parse()` y `stringify()`.

Te dejo su documentación:

- [`stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)
- [`parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Tambien he intentado alguna cosa, te dejo el código por si te da alguna idea. (Puede que tengas que editar en el método `substring()` el numero de la posición)

```js
// Tu objeto
objeto = `{'{ "data": [ { "id": "1234" } ] }'}`;

console.log("Antes: ", objeto);

// Convertimos el objeto a texto
preJson = JSON.stringify(objeto);

// Eliminamos "{'" y "'}" de la cadena, así como los espacios en blanco
preJson = preJson.substring(3, preJson.length - 3).trim();

// Quitamos las contrabarras
preJson = preJson.replace(/\\/g, "");

// Lo convertimos JSON - Es una cadena de texto formateada como JSON
json = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(preJson));

console.log("Despues: ", json);
```

Comment: Por desgracia no puedo ya que el servicio que realiza el curl no tengo permitido modificarlo

Comment: Como así? haces una pregunta sobre un curl que no puedes modificar? entonces como esperas que te ayudemos? (o en que parte me perdí?)

Comment: Solo puedo modificar el servicio que recibe el curl, es decir, el codigo que escribí en nodejs.

Comment: Y la pregunta que realicé si lees bien la hice sobre nodejs nunca sobre el curl

Comment: He editado la respuesta con alguna otra idea, espero de ayude en algo.

Answer (score 0):

Por el hecho de enviarlo como `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` en vez de `application/json` el contenido de la petición se interpreta como si viniera de un formulario

En particular, en tu caso es como un input con nombre y sin contenido:

```
<input type="text" name='{"data":[{"id":"12345"}]}' value="" />
```

No es trivial mandar algo que no sea un string mediante un formulario. Ya un arreglo de strings requiere seguir ciertas convenciones. Si cambiásemos el input a algo como:

```
<input type="text" name="data" value='[{"id":"12345"}]' />
```

Y en vez de `express.json()` usaras `express.urlencoded()` terminarías con un objeto, pero no el objeto que esperas sino

```
{ data: '[{"id":"12345"}]' }
```

**La solución** es relajar el criterio del bodyparser json, para aceptar no sólo Content-Type `application/json`. Acá le digo que acepte todo:

```
app.post('/updated' ,express.json({type: '*/*' }) , function (req, res) {
 console.info(req.body);  // -> pure win
});
```

Y eso da el resultado que buscas.

---

**Bonus Track**

les sugiero apoyarse en el importador de Postman. Es omnívoro y sirve bastante para traducir cualquier curl a un formato menos críptico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado de la importación señala lo que te dije al principio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]